# Unity how to paint a mesh in different colors with gradient

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, shader

I want to generate low poly terrain like on picture below.
I've done mesh generator. But I cannot imagine how to apply colors on that mesh. For example brown color on high angle points, light colors on flat points. And how to make gradient between colors. Can someone help me with advice what should I learn?

[image]

Comment: A shader like this probably isn't too complex, you could pass it the color for vertical normals and the color for horizontal normals and interpolate between them. [Here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaders.html) you'll find the documentatin for sufaceshaders. With the input parameter `worldNormal` you should be able to get the angle.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot Thank you so much! I think it's what I need

Answer (score 0):

The terrain data holds... well, the data for the terrain. 
exactly what the terrain data holds can be found here:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.html

you will need to do a bit of coding.
Terrain data can be accessed with something like:

```
    TerrainData terrainData = Terrain.activeTerrain.terrainData;
```

and here is a post that may be useful:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/12835/how-to-automatically-apply-different-textures-on-t.html

the code given in that post, creates a 3D array in which to store your splatmap data in and then uses the terrain data and some logic (based on the elevation of that particular block of terrain) to 'splatter' texure to give a more realistic look.

here is a random example of a terrain using a splatmap (from google):
http://www.cygengames.com/images/terrainBeautyShot09_720.png